# Как сделать два логотипа в Вордпресс?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть сайт на Вордпрес. Мне нужно создать два варианта логотипа. Для мобильних и компов. Но как это сделать. Если такого варианта нет то как получить линк фавикона?

Comment: Линк на фавикон -- `get_site_icon_url()`. Но что вообще значит что: "такого варианта нет"?

Comment: https://diveinwp.com/add-image-upload-option-to-wordpress-theme-customizer/ что-то такое, если я правильно понял

Comment: Если что - в нормальных темах всё есть из коробки. И даже для ретины можно отдельный делать ;) https://i.imgur.com/yAPylFi.jpeg